# Assertion failed after memcpy in c

Tags: c, memcpy, assertion

I have a function which creates a duplicate for a certain array.  The struct for my code is:

```
typedef struct {
  int* data;
  unsigned int len;
} intarr_t;
```

The function that I have written is:

```
intarr_t* intarr_copy( const intarr_t* ia )
{
    unsigned int len;
    intarr_t* newia = malloc(sizeof(intarr_t));
    assert (newia);
    newia->data = malloc(sizeof(int)*len);
    newia->len = len;
    if (newia == 0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy (newia->data, ia->data, len*sizeof(int));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I tested the function, it stopped my function and said that my assertion for ia failed.  The only place where I have ia is with memcpy.  But I didn't even do an assertion in my function.  Does anybody know why it gave me an assertion error?

Comment: The reason could be that you're never initializing your `len` variable to a value. It's likely that you really mean to do something like `unsigned int len = ia->len;`

Comment: len is uninitialized. also try to keep your code coherent and not mix. `NULL`, `0` and the like if you really mean the same thing. another thing is that you assert if `newia` is properly alloced and than later check for it with an if statement. I don`t really know what this code is even supposed to do since you copy around random amounts of data depending on len...

Comment: `unsigned int len = ia->len;` and intXXX_t is system reserved name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing a crash is because:

```
memcpy (newia->data, ia->data, len*sizeof(int));
```

In this line the value of `len` is indeterminate so you see a crash.
Also we see `len` is being uninitialized and being used in multiple places in the function which is not right since the value of `len` will be indeterminate without initialization.

Further there are many things which are redundant in your code.

Check for memory allocation success or failure just after calling malloc()

```
intarr_t* newia = malloc(sizeof(intarr_t));

if(newia == NULL)
{
printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
return;
}
```

So by doing this you are not accessing invalid memory.

Next, your naming conventions are too poor. You have to have readable typedef's not something like 
`intarr_t`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks for noting it I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
// the following is assuming that 'len' is the number of ints in the memory 
// pointed to by 'data'
// I would strong suggest you use variable names that indicate
// if something is a pointer 
// (typically by pre-pending 'p' 
//  and capitalizing the first letter of the rest of the variable name)

intarr_t* intarr_copy( const intarr_t* ia )
{

    intarr_t* newia = malloc(sizeof(intarr_t));

    if( NULL == newia )
    { // then, malloc failed
        perror( "malloc failed for intarr_t" )'
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc for intarr_t successful

    newia->data = malloc(sizeof(int)*ia->len);

    if( NULL == newia->data )
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc failed for int array" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc of data array successful

    // set fields in newia
    newia->len = ia->len;
    memcpy (newia->data, ia->data, (sizeof(int)*ia->len));

    return( newia );
}
```